# SharePoint 2010 not accepting "value" attribute in input tag...any alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint-2010, cewp

I am using Content Editor WebPart in SP 2010 to create a simple button control, using the following code:

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="btn1" onclick="replyclick('view');change(this);" value="+" /><label for="+"><u> Definition</u></label><br />
```

However on saving, the "value" tag vanishes just like that! Leaving behind a blank looking button.

Also, the function I am using here is a javascript and the button functions perfectly...

I am not sure if there is any other alternative to "value" to name my button?

Comment: I'm not sure what sharepoint allows but have you tried using a decimal or hex code for the plus sign in the value? Decimal is 43 and hex is 2B.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem doesn't seem to be with the value inside the quotes, but rather the tag itself. Value="Anything" gets erased completely....

Answer (score 1):

I try it on my SharePoint 2010 development environment, and it works fine. Double check your JavaScript.